# Downtime Activities - Crafting and Creating Capital

Tags: pathfinder-1e, downtime

Context: I'm a Player, Arcanist level 7. I have 2 weeks downtime which I want to optimize to the fullest!

According to RAW, the maximum crafting time for magic items is 8 hours each day.

Another 8 hours is sleep (which I'm not 100% sure about, since penalties for being tired ain't too bad for downtime).

This leaves 8 hours (or more, depending on the sleep part) for other activities. The question is: **can I spend those remaining 8 hours on making Magic Points (earning capital activity)?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No

If you look at the [rules for downtime](https://aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Downtime&Category=Gamemastering), you'll see under the [Craft Magic Items](https://aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Craft%20Magic%20Items&Category=Downtime%20Activities) activity:

> you can spend days in the downtime system to craft magic items, *with **each downtime day** counting as 8 hours of crafting time.*

Similarly, the [Earn Capital (Magic Points)](https://aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Earn%20Capital&Category=Downtime%20Activities) activity states:

> You can spend 1 day of downtime earning capital.

Since each activity takes 1 day of downtime when used, you cannot use the Earn Capital activity when you're crafting (and vice versa). Instead you need to combine the two in a way that adds up to 14 days of downtime spent, not 28.

Comment: This is gravely incorrect. Crafting magic items section clearly states You can spend a maximum of 8 hours on crafting every day. It's not a whole day.

Comment: @NecXelos And [downtime activities](https://aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Craft%20Magic%20Items&Category=Downtime%20Activities) states: "you can spend days in the downtime system to craft magic items, with **each downtime day counting as 8 hours of crafting time**"

Comment: And that's the question: what can I do in remaining time.

Comment: @NecXelos Nothing: "[Y]ou can spend **days** in the downtime system to craft magic items, with **each downtime day** counting as 8 hours of crafting time." The entire downtime day is spent but counts as 8 hours of crafting.

Comment: If you edit this answer in the future, @me and I'll reverse my downvote (it's currently locked in).  I could have sworn I remembered a sidebar in Ultimate Campaign about pacing downtime saying that a dedicated character could indeed get two "days" per day if the GM allowed it, recommending it only be used for fast-paced campaigns where it makes sense for someone to push that hard in short bursts.  But I found the sidebar and it only mentions working weekends;  I think I imagined the other part.

Comment: Tell me more about that @gatherer818. It sounds exactly like something I'm looking for, which is a loophole to make it possible.

Comment: @NecXelos [Here's the sidebar on AoN](https://aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Working%20Weekends&Category=Gaining%20Capital). Essentially, the rules for using craft and profession to gain money assumes that you don't work the weekends, but you can if you want. It won't help with this.

Comment: That is the one.  I might have gotten it confused with a house rule from one of my prior campaigns.  (That said, I would definitely allow a character with a _ring of sustenance_ or other "you only need two hours of sleep each night" ability to double up on downtime days, but at least one would need to be doable in evening/night...  but that would be a house rule.)

Comment: @gatherer818 I faintly recall there being a 3pp product that overhauls kingdom building rules, so that might be something from it you're remembering. Also, I've updated the answer to read better (imo).